# Dowload file with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my html, I have

```
$('#vcc').click(function() { get_file() } );

function get_file()
{
    $.ajax({ url: "test.php",context: document.body})
    .done(function(text)
    {
    ....
    });
}
```

In `test.php` I'm generating a pdf document.

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename("factures/facture_2015_03.pdf")));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($response));

    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo $response;
```

If I call directly test.php, it's working, the file is downloaded.

Now I'd like to have it working with an ajax call.  But I don't know what to put in the `...` I tried with a `document.write`.  The content of the pdf file is shown in my browser but not downloaded.

What can I do ?

---

EDIT:

Now my `local.php` contains

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() { document_ready(); } );

    function document_ready()
    {
        $('#vcc').click(function() { get_ajax() } );

        $.ajaxTransport("+binary", function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR)
        {
            // check for conditions and support for blob / arraybuffer response type
            if (window.FormData && ((options.dataType && (options.dataType == 'binary')) || (options.data && ((window.ArrayBuffer && options.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) || (window.Blob && options.data instanceof Blob)))))
            {
                return {
                        // create new XMLHttpRequest
                        send: function(_, callback){
                            // setup all variables
                            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                                url = options.url,
                                type = options.type,
                                // blob or arraybuffer. Default is blob
                                dataType = options.responseType || "blob",
                                data = options.data || null;

                            xhr.addEventListener('load', function(){
                                var data = {};
                                data[options.dataType] = xhr.response;
                                // make callback and send data
                                callback(xhr.status, xhr.statusText, data, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                            });

                            xhr.open(type, url, true);
                            xhr.responseType = dataType;
                            xhr.send(data);
                        },
                        abort: function(){
                            jqXHR.abort();
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
        }

        function get_ajax()
        {
            $.ajax({
                  url: "remote.php",
                  // data that you want send to PHP script
                  data: { fileId: "random", extraData: "some value" },
                  type: "GET", // or POST
                  dataType: "binary", // make our special transfer type
                  processData: false,
                  success: function(text)
                  {
                  var pdfContent = [text]; // change to Array
                  var fakeFile= new Blob(pdfContent, {type: 'application/pdf'});
                  SaveToDisk(fakeFile, "form1.pdf")
                  }
                });
        }

        function SaveToDisk(blobURL, fileName) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blobURL);
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                var save = document.createElement('a');
                save.href = event.target.result;
                save.target = '_blank';
                save.download = fileName || 'unknown file';

                var event = document.createEvent('Event');
                event.initEvent('click', true, true);
                save.dispatchEvent(event);
                (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
            };
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <input type="submit" id="vcc" value="Go"></input>
</div>

</body>
```

and `remote.php`

```
<?php 

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename("form1.pdf")));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

$response = readfile("form1.pdf");

header('Content-Length:' . strlen($response));

ob_clean();
flush();

print  $response;

?>
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: Is there a readon why you don't use a normal link with download-attribute? http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute

Comment: It's because the pdf file is only generated when I send the ajax request.  And it is not saved on the server.

Comment: Do you send POST parameters? Otherwise you can simply link to test.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure [my other solution with jQuery does not work in Firefox..]. Like many others said, you should not use AJAX/jQuery to make web browser download file.

Example:

**page.htm** with download link/button/anything:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Download fake file from JS script example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
function downloadPdfExample()
{
    // simple :)
    window.location = "download_pdf.php";
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Click on button below to start download:<br />
<button onclick="downloadPdfExample()">Start PDF download</button><br />

</body>
</html>
```

**download_pdf.php** file that will force browser to download file, not show in new card/current card:

```
<?php
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename("form1.pdf")));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile("example.pdf");

flush();
```

I thought too much about JS code and forgot about PHP.

As you can see in example on PHP page ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2524 ) **readfile('filename');** does not return file content. It prints it on 'output'!

So.. this part of code:

```
$response = readfile("form1.pdf");
header('Content-Length:' . strlen($response));
```

Throws error! You cannot set response *header* AFTER you send file content (*readfile* send file content to browser, not put it variable *$response*!)

In *$response* is LENGTH of data sent to browser, so *strlen($reponse)* also does not work.

Comment: Hello JerzySkalski.  Ok it seems to be the only solution working.  It's not exactly what I wanted to do but it's working fine like that.  Thanks for taking some time to help me.  For the readfile, according to the documentation it's not good like I do but ... you can test it it's working like that !

Comment: If your PHP code from first post works like it should on your web server, it means that you got some bugged webserver. I put it on my server: http://skalski.at/example/readfile_test/test.php and it send file with content '27' (length of string in file test_file.txt ). After I removed **ob_clean()** [**ob_clean()** removes everything that your PHP script generated and your webserver did not send to web browser yet] it shows 'ST' (first 2 letters on .txt file). After I removed **header(.. with length of file ..)** it works like it should.. except it shows '27' after my file content!

Comment: You can also check if my other code with jQuery download work in other browsers then Chrome (maybe it will in future). Proper implementation you can test here: http://skalski.at/example/fake_file_download/page.htm

Answer (score 1):

You **can't download** a file using **JavaScript/JQuery**...simply, because they are unable to create file on client side
You can put a link to download your file instead

```
<a href="test.php">Download file </a>
```

Or you can use a pure **JavaScript** redirection

```
document.location.href = "test.php"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create file in new browsers (IE only 10+, all Chrome, Firefox, Safari..).

Code to save generated file:

```
function SaveToDisk(blobURL, fileName) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blobURL);
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var save = document.createElement('a');
        save.href = event.target.result;
        save.target = '_blank';
        save.download = fileName || 'unknown file';

        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        save.dispatchEvent(event);
        (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    };
}
```

Code to generate file:

```
var pdfContent = ['file content']; // create Array bytes of file or with it's content as string
var fakeFile= new Blob(pdfContent, {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

Force browser to save it on disc:

```
SaveToDisk(fakeFile, "my.pdf")
```

---

**EDIT:**

PDF files - as many others - are in 'binary' format which is not default in JS, but jQuery let us make 'plugins' to add new features like that (transfer binary files, full tutorial: http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/ )

Add this somewhere 'after jQuery load' and 'before AJAX call':

```
$.ajaxTransport("+binary", function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR){
    // check for conditions and support for blob / arraybuffer response type
    if (window.FormData && ((options.dataType && (options.dataType == 'binary')) || (options.data && ((window.ArrayBuffer && options.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) || (window.Blob && options.data instanceof Blob)))))
    {
        return {
            // create new XMLHttpRequest
            send: function(_, callback){
                // setup all variables
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                    url = options.url,
                    type = options.type,
                    // blob or arraybuffer. Default is blob
                    dataType = options.responseType || "blob",
                    data = options.data || null;

                xhr.addEventListener('load', function(){
                    var data = {};
                    data[options.dataType] = xhr.response;
                    // make callback and send data
                    callback(xhr.status, xhr.statusText, data, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                });

                xhr.open(type, url, true);
                xhr.responseType = dataType;
                xhr.send(data);
            },
            abort: function(){
                jqXHR.abort();
            }
        };
    }
});
```

You **ajax** call should look like this [remember to add function **SaveToDisc** from code above]:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "generate/pdf/test.php",
  // data that you want send to PHP script
  data: { fileId: "random", extraData: "some value" },
  type: "GET", // or POST
  dataType: "binary", // make our special transfer type
  processData: false,
  success: function(text){
  var pdfContent = [text]; // change to Array
  var fakeFile= new Blob(pdfContent, {type: 'application/pdf'});
  SaveToDisk(fakeFile, "myPdfDownloader.pdf")
  }
});
```

I did tests again and it works for me. I hope you can accept my answer now :)

Comment: I'm trying your solution.  I've put 3 lines above in the .done.  But nothing happens.  Having the ajax call like in my question, what should I put in pdfContent ?  var pdfContent = test; ?

Comment: I added more information and tested PDF transfer (which must be binary - without binary transfer, it would create big PDF file which is full of empty pages). In **test.php** you must generate PDF file content that you can view by browser. **With all these 'jQuery transfer' changes, it should work, even if you don't set in PHP, that it's PDF file/force download and other 'headers'**

Comment: Thanks JerzySkalski.  I just tried your solution but I don't understand what I'm missing because it's not working.  I edited my question to put my code.  I'm using firefox 35.  I also tried with jquery 1.11.2.  No download box and no pdf on the disk.

Comment: I did tests with site:

http://skalski.at/example/fake_file_download/page.htm

and this code does not work (not save file) in Firefix :( Read my other answer, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you when you click a link or a text div to download the document ,you do not want the page to be directed to that php file,insted ,you want it in the same page without being routed another page via JQUERY .You need to call the ajax method in jquery.
Make sure you included the corrected and updated libraries of JQuery.Then assume that you want the document named "ozan" to be downloaded via ajax.Then I assume in the text of it is "ozan" then in jquery you can write it as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#document_name").click(function(){
var documentname=$(this).val();
$.ajax({method:"POST",
url:"test.php",
data:{name:documentname},
success:function(incoming){`
alert("Downloading...");
}
});});
```

When you create your ajax it will send document name automatically in test.php without refreshing the page then get the value in that php as:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
$document_name=$_POST["name"];
}
```

> Then you can write your download code below this code snippet in that php file

Comment: I tried your code, but I don't understand what ozan have to do with it ;-)  More seriously, the ajax call is done, the alert box is showing but ... then ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a download button with download attribute:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp